# Spring MVC App Metrics Frameworks

Tags: spring, performance, spring-mvc, monitoring, metrics

I have a REST webservice written using Spring MVC 4.latest
The service will be deployed on AWS Opsworks.

I want to have graph showing metrics like: tp90, total requests per second/hour/day, detailed by request uri if possible.
Also if possible DB queries response time.

I would like this to be put in something like Cloudwatch or maybe Ganglia (?)

Is there a framework that does this already? 
Any other suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: I am also looking to add some kind of metrics and doing research. I come across this http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html. Not sure how to use it without Spring boot though.

Comment: I ended up using Dropwizard Metrics with Ganglia, it seems to integrate pretty well with Spring